# Crawling generated source of page

Tags: curl

I am trying to crawl the source of [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1042957396902089) website of a research article, exploiting a redirect from it's Document Object Identifier (DOI):

```
doi=10.1006/jfin.1996.0208
url=$(curl -L -s -w %{url_effective} "http://dx.doi.org/"$doi -o /dev/null)
curl -L --referer ";auto" $url > test.htm --dump-header /dev/null
```

The file/source however looks different from what I see when I open the link in the browser. For example, the list of references is limited to 20 entries, and instead of showing links to these items, I only see "Loading".

Obviously, the source is different from what the browser (FF) shows me. Indeed, when I take a look at the site's source file using [this](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/webdevel.html#generated_source) bookmarklet to view generated source, I get the complete source file I want to have.

Now is there a way to crawl the generated source of a webpage? Taking a look at [this](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/curl.htm) detailed manual, I couldn't find anything related to generated source.

Answer (score 1):

Curl only does the "main" page. If there is any content on the page that is loaded by JavaScript, you will not get that in your scraping/crawling when you use `curl`.

The best way to get a "complete" pages that I have found is use [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and drive that from some script (I use python to do so). Complete is relative here, because there is no guarantee **ever** that JavaScript is done loading.

E.g. in a python virtualenv, run:

```
pip install selenium
python dl.py  http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/210268/33055 /var/tmp/page.html 5
```

with `dl.py`:

```
import sys
import time
from selenium import webdriver

url, file_name, seconds = sys.argv[1:4]
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
try:
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(int(seconds))
    with open(file_name, 'w') as fp:
        fp.write(browser.find_element_by_xpath('html').get_attribute(
            "outerHTML").encode('utf-8'))
finally:
    browser.close()
```

Comment: What selenium part of Selenium would you use to crawl? IDE or WebDriver?

Comment: @MERose I use the webdriver (`from selenium import webdriver`  etc). You can of course just have python retrieve and dump the page and then process the dumped html with the normal tools. If you don't have to login to something, and just can wait a few seconds until the page is done loading than that is only a few lines of code. Do you need an example?

Comment: @MERose example provided. The saved page will not look the same as you don't have the original CSS properly loaded, but the HTML content should be the same.